# Stored Procedure with syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

i have the following code that is giving me a headache, i need to create this stored procedure for a database, however, i can save it nor implement it due to a Syntax error at 'AS'. I need to know what am i doing wrong?

```
Create PROCEDURE `insert_delete_update` (OUT
 id int,
 level varchar(225),
 action varchar(20)
 )

AS    
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @Action = 'Insert'
BEGIN
insert into levels (id, level) values(@id, @level)   
END

IF @Action = 'Select'
BEGIN
select * from levels
END 

IF @Action = 'Update'
BEGIN
UPDATE levels SET
            level =  @level
      WHERE id = @id
END

else IF @Action = 'Delete'
BEGIN
DELETE FROM levels WHERE id = @id
END
END
```

Comment: PS: I'm using this code directly into MySQL Workbench, so that's why the "delimiter //" is missing.

Comment: Example of creating store procedure to refer this link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/

Comment: I tried that, no good, if i remove "AS" i get a lot more syntax errors. I really don't get it, honestly.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: Thaks Mr. Kalgude, i will take a look on that, however i want to know what's wrong with this one as a stored procedure itself.

Comment: remove AS and then you will get actual syntax errors and you can work to sort out them...

Comment: Alright so i made some adjusments, however i'm still getting a syntax error at one of the END; saying i'm missing an END...(the bold one)
`Create PROCEDURE insert_delete_update ()
BEGIN
Declare  id int;
Declare level varchar(225);
Declare action varchar(20);

Set @Action = 'Insert';
BEGIN
insert into levels (id, level) values(@id, @level);
END;
 
SET @Action = 'Select';
BEGIN
select * from levels
END ;

SET @Action = 'Update';
BEGIN
UPDATE levels SET
            level =  @level
      WHERE id = @id;
**END;**

else IF @Action = 'Delete'
BEGIN
DELETE FROM levels WHERE id = @id
END;
END`

Answer (score 0):

Right so i finally got my answer.

Here is the final code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_delete_update`()
BEGIN
Declare  id int;
Declare level varchar(225);
Declare action varchar(20);

Set @Action = 'Insert';
BEGIN
insert into levels (id, level) values(@id, @level);
END;

SET @Action = 'Select';
BEGIN
select * from levels
END ;

SET @Action = 'Update';
BEGIN
UPDATE levels SET
            level =  @level
      WHERE id = @id;
END;

SET @Action = 'Delete';
BEGIN
DELETE FROM levels WHERE id = @id;
END;
END;
END
```

Thx for all your help!

Comment: Syntactically valid, but still wrong.  The parameter variables like `action` should not have `@` before them, because that references a user-defined variable, not a program variable (there are two different scopes and namespaces).  Your program variables cannot use the same names as column names, because that creates ambiguity `WHERE id = id` ... bye bye data in the entire table.

Answer (score -1):

I have written stored procedure for you. You can use it and I hope it will resolve your problem. I have created from workbench only.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_delete_update`(OUT
     id int,
     level varchar(225),
     action varchar(20))
BEGIN
        if @action = 'Insert' THEN
            insert into levels (id, level) values(@id, @level) ;   
        elseif @action = 'Select' THEN
            select * from levels ;
        elseif @action = 'Update' THEN
            UPDATE levels SET
                        level =  @level
                  WHERE id = @id;
        elseif @action = 'Delete' THEN
            DELETE FROM levels WHERE id = @id;
        end if;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You have used user defined variables instead of program variables.  This code may be syntactically valid but not logically valid.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, please provide the correct answer I will also learn from your experience

Comment: When time permits, I will do that.